# What does laissez vibrer mean on a wind instrument?

Tags: notation, trombone, ties, bassoon

I'm a bassoonist and when I play in a wind band I often get given a trombone part.

Sometimes I have to transpose a score because it is in E♭. And sometimes I have to transpose passages that are too high for me to play. I won't be of a standard to play the solos in *Rite of Spring* anytime soon. So I find myself writing out a lot of scores in a different clef or octave.

Last week I got a score that appeared to have a note tied to the following rest, as appears in bar 49. This is the way I transcribed it[image: bars 47-50] but the bar in the original trombone part looked like this
[image]

My notation reference (Gould, *Behind bars,* 72) tells me that this is an "open tie" which is also indicated *laissez vibrer*.

Now, I understand what this means for a stringed instrument. It means "don't damp the string at the rest".

But my reed won't continue vibrating when I stop blowing, and I must assume something similar applies to trombones.

So clearly the notation doesn't really mean *laissez vibrer:* it's some sort of metaphor. Can anyone explain what it does mean?

Comment: I’d put my money on it being a mistake

Comment: @ToddWilcox Umm. If I look again at the bars before it, that seems very plausible. Thanks for supplying a clearly necessary dose of commonsense.

Comment: Not a string part surely, unless it's on a cello or bass (especially a pizzicato note) or maybe on an open string. It's more common in music for percussion instruments, harps, pianos, guitars etc.

Comment: Note, this isn't necessarily a direction of *laissez vibrer*; until proven guilty it's just a misplaced slur. Occam's razor says it's much more likely that a note got deleted or a slur got accidentally copy/pasted than that it's meaningful.

Comment: @Andy Bonner: That's true.

Comment: I don't understand the new title. Is there some reason to have removed the original one? It seemed very clear.

Comment: @Aaron Thank you for pointing that out. It was finger trouble on my part.

Comment: Thanks for adding the original. See the edit on my answer.

Comment: Pretty sure that’s **not** an l.v. tie! I think that’s a fall.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I'm not sure I believe it's a fall on a ♪ in an ensemble rhythm part at a tempo of =76. But that's why I asked the question, so I'm not going to argue.

Comment: What piece (title, composer) is this, please?

Comment: @Aaron It's a band arrangement by J.-P. Labaste of *Bad Romance* by Lady Gaga (2009).

Answer (score 4):

Was the music in a jazz style?   What we have here, I think, is a 'fall'.  An instruction to fall off the pitch at the end of a note.

Here are some more 'jazz articulations' from http://www.timusic.net/debreved/jazz-notation/

[image]

Comment: No, not jazz: pop. But in any case the composer or arranger should not be using a tapered tie/slur arc for any of those.

Comment: Agreed. Now that I see the mark I don’t think it’s a tie at all.

Answer (score 3):

I have no experience with reed instruments, but on wind instruments like a flute you can end a note two ways: 1. by stopping to blow / slightly opening your lips vs 2. by letting your tongue stop the air stream. If I came across an open tie I would interpret it as the former, which -- very modestly -- causes a tapering off of the note.

And looking at your original trombone part I think it means that you also let the note slide down in pitch. On a flute I'd do that by rolling the instrument in. No idea if there is an equivalent on a bassoon.

Comment: Yeah I think it’s a fall which is not uncommon in brass parts.

Comment: @ToddWilcox Ah, is that what it's called.

Answer (score 1):

I'll be "that guy" and go against the crowd here.  I've seen similar markings here and there which were deliberately created by the composer to stress that the played note should be held right up to the start of the rest.  This stops musicians (either inexperienced or lazy) from terminating the sound sooner than intended.

So it's not exactly "laissez vibrer" but more of an indicator of desired note length.

Comment: Why not just put a tenuto over the note?

Comment: This seems plausible.  Maybe what was meant was "if this were a different instrument, *laisser vibrer* would make literal sense; here, interpret it figuratively."

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to thank all the people who answered or commented. The consensus appears to be *it depends*, so I can't reasonably accept one answer above the others.

The first issue, raised in an early comment, was *Is this accidental or deliberate?* I initially assumed it was deliberate, but that assumption was no doubt coloured by the fact that I use Dorico, which makes doing it by accident very hard. Since it's not a notation I ever need, even to read, it took me a while to find out what it was, and how to do it deliberately.

The comments reminded me that it is in fact easy to do, deliberately or accidentally, in other software: simply copy a bar with a pair of slurred notes and delete the second of the pair in the copy. Sibelius, MuseScore, and even old Encore will all let you do that. Sibelius will let you do it with tied notes, too, which looks better, though you might not like the resulting playback. I'm not familiar with Finale, which I know for a fact was used to prepare the trombone score, but I'm guessing it's similar.

And if it is deliberate, then the right interpretation might depend on the kind of music, or the composer/arranger's tendency to make the slur arc serve for things other than slurs: suggestions here included *tenuto,*  *> al niente* and *fall*.

That would be unremarkable. Even when used conventionally, slurs have different meanings for wind (legato), strings (bow-stroke), and voice (syllable).

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in the two bars before. As you can see the last two 8th notes are connected with a slur in both bars. The composer wants you to play that last B in m49 as if it legatoes into a next note, except it's a rest this time.

So yes, you might say it's a tenuto, but the intent is slightly different. I'd play it as a tenuto with a rather smooth ending, not too abrupt.

I don't find this ambiguous at all TBH and would notate it the same way.